# Get Result set in SQL for the last 12 months starting from current date

Tags: sql, database, recursion, recursive-query

So I'm trying to get the data from my DB for the last 12 months. I have a very big stored procedure, where I first calculated data not depending on timespan. 
Firstly on my SP i calculate one container where I get some data like year, month, id etc. The the other calculations are based on these data (id, month, year).

Now my boss decided to calculate only data only for the past 12months. But I can't wrap my mind around it. I was thinkig creating a recursive CTE(Common Table Expression), where I calculate only the last 12 months. Maybe you guys have a different opinion. Let me show you my starting query. :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year, Month, BId, DCode, ParentB_ID AS [PId]
  FROM [s].SK k
  join Businesses b on b.id = k.BId
  left join AD d on k.BId = d.DID
  WHERE SName = 'New Test'
```

This query returns me this :

```
Year Month  BId   DCode  PId
---- -----  ----  -----  ---
2018  12    12    NULL   NULL
2018  12    20    NULL   1
2018  12    33    NULL   26
2018  12    19    NULL   20
```

What is suppossed to return now are only data from ***year = 2019, and month = 3*** until now.

What I was trying was this:

```
;WITH ACCC  
  AS
  (
        SELECT DISTINCT Year, Month, BId, d.DCode, P_ID AS [ParentId]
        FROM [s].SK k
        join Businesses b on b.id = k.BId
        left join AD d on k.BId = d.D_ID
        WHERE SName = 'New Test' 
        //AND add here the logic for selecting data only for the last 12 months. 
        //Starting from current and ascending

          CROSS JOIN

        SELECT DISTINCT Year, Month, BId, d.DCode, P_ID AS [ParentId]
        FROM [s].SK s
        INNER JOIN   ACCC P
        ON P.BId = s.D_ID
  )
  SELECT Year, Month, BId, d.DCode, P_ID AS [ParentId]
  FROM AC
```

Am I in the right track with this CTE. Is there any other way?

I'm really strugling with this guys. Any help I would appreciate a lot. 
Thank you a lot in advance :)

Comment: Recursive CTEs use `UNION ALL`, not `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: What MySQL version used?

Comment: CTE is useful for readability while recursive CTE, AFAIK, is when you have a parent-child relationship within your table. I don't understand the connection with filtering for the past 12 months. Aside from Year and Month columns, is there a date field in your table that represents that? You can use GetDate then add -12 months and get the FilterYear and FilterMonth of the earliest record you'd like to fetch so WHERE Year > FilterYear OR (Year = FilterYear AND Month >= FilterMonth)

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are totally right. My mistake... Any idea regarding my problem sir?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I'm using actually Sql, not my sql.

Comment: @jegtugado Hello. Actually on table I have a parent-child relationship. Where I'm supposed to get only certain childs which belong only to certain Parents.
How do I get the filter of the earliest date?  Can you please show me, on an answer below?

Comment: Please provide source table data. Check --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the Year and Month then you can filter the past 12 months like the following:

(This is T-SQL/SQL Server)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Foo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Foo;

CREATE TABLE #Foo (
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    [Month] INT NOT NULL,
    Bar VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2018, 1, 'NO');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2018, 12, 'NO');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2019, 1, 'NO');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2019, 2, 'NO');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2019, 3, 'YES');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2019, 4, 'YES');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2019, 5, 'YES');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2019, 12, 'YES');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2020, 1, 'YES');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2020, 2, 'YES');
INSERT INTO #Foo([Year], [Month], Bar) VALUES (2020, 3, 'YES');

SELECT  [Year], [Month], Bar
FROM    #Foo
WHERE   [Year] > YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
        OR ([Year] = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) 
            AND [Month] >= MONTH(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: Declaring a variable to store `YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))` and `MONTH(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))` would be an improvement since the query wouldn't have to evaluate it per record.